# Make Loading Image Appear After Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I want to make a loading image appear more than one time after click a button? I managed to get the loading image appear once but after click on the button again, the image won't appear. Below are my code,

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("input:submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isclicked = false;

    if (!isclicked) {
      $(".fa-spin").show();
      setClicked();
    }

    // set data and values here
    $.ajax({
      url: "insert-slip.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: fd,
      processData: false,  
      contentType: false  
    }).done(function(data){
      $('#result_insert').html(data);
      $(".fa-spin").hide();
    });

    function setClicked(){
       isclicked = true;
    }

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="result_insert">
  <div class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></div>
</div>
```

**Solutions**

Below are the answer for my question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("input:submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#result_insert").empty();
    $(".fa-spin").show();

    // set data and values here
    $.ajax({
      url: "insert-slip.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: fd,
      processData: false,  
      contentType: false  
    }).done(function(data){
      $('#result_insert').html(data);
      $(".fa-spin").hide();
    });
  });
});

<div class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></div> 
<div id="result_insert"></div>
```

Comment: Remove all the things about `isClicked`

Comment: Move var isClicked = false outside the listener.

Comment: Hey, if you want to get loading image on every click, why are you even writing isclicked variable? Why do you need that

Comment: Your `isclicked` logic is entirely redundant and can be removed

Comment: `#result_insert` is replaced by `data`, that maybe remove the `.fa-spin`element

Comment: @MehulMohan previously, I did not use the setClicked function. Will remove it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I don't understand all the commotion about the `isclicked`. As it currently stands, it doesn't serve a purpose, but since the variable is scoped to the click handler, it shouldn't cause any issues either. The only reason to keep the `isclicked` would be to prevent concurrent AJAX requests, but then you'd have to move the variable declaration out of the click handler and the AJAX call into the `if (!isclicked) {}` block.

Comment: thanks for the advice @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the spinner by replacing the contents of the `result_insert` element with the data you get back from the AJAX request:

```
$('#result_insert').html(data);
```

Move the spinner outside of the `result_insert` element:

```
<div id="result_insert"></div>
<div class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! If I want to replace the loading image with the result, should I hide the `#result_insert` first. eg when click; appear loading image > hide loading image > appear result. On the next click, hide result > appear loading image > hide loading image > appear new result.

Comment: I wouldn't hide the result, just empty it out on every click.

Comment: Just to reconfirm, after the on click function, I will put `$("#result_insert").empty();`.

Answer (score 1):

In ajax Function add `beforeSend` add spinner logic to it and `done` update image to target div

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("input:submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "insert-slip.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: fd,
      processData: false,  
      contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#result_insert').html('<div class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></div>')
        }
    }).done(function(data){
      $('#result_insert').html(data);
    });
    });
});
```

Html

`<div id="result_insert"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

When button is clicked your code replaces the content inside `result_insert` after successful ajax call, which removes `fa-spin` div that is the reason why spinner is not visible on subsequent button clicks

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></div>
  <div id="result_insert"></div>
</div>
```

This will do the job for her.